# Java/JavaMail: Null pointer exception when trying to create a folder to fetch E-Mails (GMAIL/POP3)

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

Everything works, including authentication, but when I get to the step of creating a folder the program crashes.

I've tried switching to SMTP, didn't work, not even sure what SMTP is,
I've Tried a different Gmail account,
I've tried removing the line `properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true")`, and
I've tried removing the 3's from `pop3` and `pop3s`.

```java
    private static void createProperties() {
        // Create properties field.

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        //properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

        emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    }

    private static void createStore() throws MessagingException {
        // Create the POP3 store object and connect with the POP server.

        Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
        store.connect(host, user, password);
    }

    private static void createFolder() throws MessagingException {
        // Create the folder object and open it.

        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX"); // Error here
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    }
```

I expected to get some nicely formatted email messages.
I got the following errors:

````
DEBUG POP3: server doesn't support TOP, disabling it 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GetMail.createFolder(GetMail.java:60)
    at GetMail.main(GetMail.java:33)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The POP3 protocol only supports one folder - Inbox.  Use IMAP instead.